# Google Sheets - Flattening a table into two columns, but returning results based on varying conditions

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, flatten, google-query-language

My table has data similar to the following:
[Raw Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6R6y3.png)

I am flattening the data into two columns using the following:

=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(SheetName!B1:D=TRUE, SheetName!B1:D1&"×"&SheetName!A1:A,)), "×"),"where Col2 is not null order by Col1 asc"))

The result is depicted here:
[Flattened Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdBSb.png)

However, I also need to return within the "flattened data" columns the following:

1@email.com | 1@email.com

2@email.com | 2@email.com

3@email.com | 3@email.com

In other words, I need to return SheetName!A1:A&"×"&SheetName!A1:A for each email address contained in the email column (Column A), in addition to the other data that is being flattened into the column. I have tried variations using IF/IFS statements, wildcards (not permitted within IFs), etc. However, I am now seeking some help after striking out many times. Thanks for any help you can offer!

**Update** Example spreadsheet with sample data and current vs. desired results (formula in cell H2):
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wq9kR4UqYeWsqSCbnkGGHbR-TIHTfaBb_ixGk41X2cs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Example spreadsheet with sample data and current vs. desired results (formula in cell H2):
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wq9kR4UqYeWsqSCbnkGGHbR-TIHTfaBb_ixGk41X2cs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(SheetName!B1:D=TRUE, 
 SheetName!B1:D1&"×"&SheetName!A1:A&"×"&SheetName!A1:A,)), "×"),
 "where Col3 is not null order by Col1 asc"))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=INDEX({QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 IF(Sheet1!B1:F=TRUE, Sheet1!B1:F1&"×"&Sheet1!A1:A,)), "×"),
 "where Col2 is not null order by Col1"); 
 TEXT(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A, A2:A<>"")), {"@", "@"})})
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm. Is the semicolon allowing you to pass separate arguments/formulas because they are within a query?

Comment: @MichaelWinthrop within {} array, if you want to put something under something else you use ; semicolon for that. the only requirement is that both things needs to have equal number of columns. to put something next to something else we use , comma within {} arrays. then the requirement is: both arrays need to have same number of rows